# Redirect non-www to www https Apache XAMPP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, redirect

Please forgive what may sound like a similar question to what has been asked, however, I am VERY new to XAMPP and Apache and I have tried all possible combinations of the Rewrite Rules mentioned in other threads, which I have placed in the `httpd.conf`, `httpd-default.conf` and also in `.htaccess` and I simply cannot get the rewrite rules to work.

I simply want to redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com`. Please note that my redirect from HTTP to HTTPS is working 100%, so if someone can please advise on exactly where I should place the rewrite rule, and which one to use, to force non-www to www, I would be most appreciative.

I have full access to the server so I can edit either `.conf` or `.htaccess` files. Also I have checked and the part in `httpd.conf` that allows overrides to read the `.htaccess` files is enabled. The `.htaccess` file is currently in the same folder where my website lies. Just to add, I don't get any error, it just says the page has timed out if I type in `example.com`, if I type `www.example.com` then the page loads as expected.

Comment: "the page has timed out if I type in `example.com`" - That would imply your server is not even configured to accept requests to the domain apex (so there's no point implementing a redirect until you do). Also, where and how have you implemented the HTTP to HTTPS redirect?

Comment: @MrWhite I have the following in my httpd.conf file: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your .htaccess file:

Replace example.com with your url.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: thank you but no go. Still just gives me "The connection has timed out". Just to clarify, the .htaccess file is the root of my website folder, not in the htdocs folder. Could this be the issue? Apache is configured to point the the website folder.

Comment: That shouldn’t be the issue. Are you hosting your own site or using a web host? The issue might be connectivity if you are using a web host.

Comment: I am hosting my own site on my own Windows Server 2008 with XAMPP. As stated if I put www in front I get my website no problem.

Comment: Is your sever configured to accept requests on port 80? That might be the issue if you can’t access the pages.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "is my server configured to accept requests on port 80?". In Apache it is configured to accept on port 80 yes, then as stated above I have redirect to HTTPS port 443.

Comment: Are www and non-www being redirected to HTTPS? If not that may be the problem because the non-www is trying to connect on port 80 while you want it to connect to port 443. If not that, idk.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> The connection has timed out
> ```

This is a DNS or server config error. The request is not even reaching your server, or your server is not responding to the request. (So any attempt to implement a redirect will naturally fail.)

A quick check of the DNS for `example.com` and `www.example.com` shows they are pointing to different IP addresses (you have an `A` record configured for each). The `example.com` host is 1 digit different and would appear to be incorrect (the IP address does not respond to requests, hence the "time out").

Instead of having a separate `A` record for each hostname. If the www subdomain is supposed to point to the same site as the domain apex (ie. `example.com`) then configure a `CNAME` record instead that points `www.example.com` to `example.com` (this is not a "redirect").

You then need to ensure that your server will accept requests to the non-www hostname. For example:

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
```

(It's possible you have the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` reversed - which is "OK".)

And the SSL cert needs to cover the non-www hostname (it does).

You can then implement your non-www to www HTTP redirect as mentioned.

Comment: may be on to something, so I have changed my DNS records, now just waiting for them to update then I will be back to answer for sure.

Comment: thank you, changing the DNS records seemed to help, however the only redirect directives that are working, for me at least, are the following:  RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] (sorry I have no idea how to start a new paragraph or to put the code into a grey block)